# When we write printf() in C, are we declaring it or defining?

Tags: c

When we are writing `printf()` in C, are we declaring it or defining?
If it is a definition then where is the declaration and vice versa?

Comment: Neither. You're calling it.

Comment: You are calling it.

Comment: `printf()` is an error, so neither. (A call to printf would have arguments, and appear in a context where an expression is required)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we are writing [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) in C, we are making a call to `printf`,
which has a *declaration* in the `<stdio.h>` header like this `int printf(const char *format, ...);`, and we should include that header in the C program.

The *definition* of `printf` is in the standard library implementation that
gets linked with the application code.

Comment: Formally it doesn't have to be in that header - it could be in a header included by that one. Nice answer nonetheless.

Comment: How i can see definition of `printf()`?

Answer (score 5):

You are doing neither: you're simply *calling* a function that's part of the C standard library.

When you `#include` the header containing the declaration of `printf` you are *declaring* it.

The *definition* is probably part of the pre-compiled bundle that ships with your compiler. But it might be inlined in a header. For some functions, the compiler itself might supply the definition.

Answer (score 0):

printf is a predefined function in the stdio header. You neither declare it nor define it, you use it.

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` is a function that has been built in the `<stdio.h>` library. As a result, when you `#include <stdio.h>` you are bringing in the declaration so that the function will be linked in.

[stdio.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/) and [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)